# How to show multiple lines in a d3 line graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am looking to draw multiple lines in a d3 line graph and transition each line with an animation. Here is a working example but with 1 line shown at a time.

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_change_data.html

I am trying to extend it to show multiple lines at the same time. And then when clicking the Dataset 2 button, it shows a new set of lines, and transitions each one. My attempt is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d6unkots/)

```js
// Create 2 datasets
var data1 = [
  [{
      ser1: 0.3,
      ser2: 4
    },
    {
      ser1: 2,
      ser2: 16
    },
    {
      ser1: 3,
      ser2: 8
    }
  ],
  [{
      ser1: 1,
      ser2: 7
    },
    {
      ser1: 4,
      ser2: 1
    },
    {
      ser1: 6,
      ser2: 8
    }
  ]
];

var data2 = [
  [{
      ser1: 4,
      ser2: 7
    },
    {
      ser1: 2,
      ser2: 5
    },
    {
      ser1: 2,
      ser2: 3
    }
  ],
  [{
      ser1: 1,
      ser2: 10
    },
    {
      ser1: 5,
      ser2: 8
    },
    {
      ser1: 7,
      ser2: 3
    }
  ]
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Initialise a X axis:
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("class", "myXaxis")

// Initialize an Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")

// Create a function that takes a dataset as input and update the plot:
function update(data) {

  // Create the X axis:
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.ser1;
    });
  })]);
  svg.selectAll(".myXaxis").transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .call(xAxis);

  // create the Y axis
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.ser2;
    });
  })]);
  svg.selectAll(".myYaxis")
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .call(yAxis);

  data.forEach(function(data, i) {

    // Create a update selection: bind to the new data
    var u = svg.selectAll(`.lineTest${i}`)
      .data([data], function(d) {
        return d.ser1
      });

    // Update the line
    u
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", `.lineTest${i}`)
      .merge(u)
      .transition()
      .duration(3000)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.ser1);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.ser2);
        }))
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2.5);

  });
}

// At the beginning, I run the update function on the first dataset:
update(data1);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add 2 buttons -->
<button onclick="update(data1)">Dataset 1</button>
<button onclick="update(data2)">Dataset 2</button>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

But the issue is, when I click the Dataset 2 button, it draws the new lines, the old lines still show, and there is no transition between them.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is working as you want here: https://jsfiddle.net/kqjcobah/. A couple things though: data joins will take care of the recursion, so no need for `forEach`. When you set the class, don't put the period in - only put the period when you select a class. I moved the line function out to a variable as well. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

1. As @Ryan Morton noted, just pass the entire set of lines to d3, it takes care of the rest. No need for a `forEach`;
2. You used `attr('class', '.lineTest')`, but that gave it a class that started with a dot. That made it impossible to select using `d3.select('.lineTest')`. Removing the dot fixed that;
3. Since your key function selects `d.ser1`, but `d` is an array of objects, `ser1` is undefined. I updated the key function to just use the index instead.

```js
// Create 2 datasets
var data1 = [
  [{
      ser1: 0.3,
      ser2: 4
    },
    {
      ser1: 2,
      ser2: 16
    },
    {
      ser1: 3,
      ser2: 8
    }
  ],
  [{
      ser1: 1,
      ser2: 7
    },
    {
      ser1: 4,
      ser2: 1
    },
    {
      ser1: 6,
      ser2: 8
    }
  ]
];

var data2 = [
  [{
      ser1: 4,
      ser2: 7
    },
    {
      ser1: 2,
      ser2: 5
    },
    {
      ser1: 2,
      ser2: 3
    }
  ],
  [{
      ser1: 1,
      ser2: 10
    },
    {
      ser1: 5,
      ser2: 8
    },
    {
      ser1: 7,
      ser2: 3
    }
  ]
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Initialise a X axis:
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("class", "myXaxis")

// Initialize an Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")

// Create a function that takes a dataset as input and update the plot:
function update(data) {

  // Create the X axis:
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.ser1;
    });
  })]);
  svg.selectAll(".myXaxis").transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .call(xAxis);

  // create the Y axis
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
      return d.ser2;
    });
  })]);
  svg.selectAll(".myYaxis")
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .call(yAxis);

  // Create a update selection: bind to the new data
  var lines = svg.selectAll(`.lineTest`)
    .data(data, function(d, i) {
      return i;
    });

  lines.exit()
    .remove();

  // Update the line
  lines.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "lineTest")
    .merge(lines)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.ser1);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.ser2);
      }))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2.5);
}

// At the beginning, I run the update function on the first dataset:
update(data1);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add 2 buttons -->
<button onclick="update(data1)">Dataset 1</button>
<button onclick="update(data2)">Dataset 2</button>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```